# can I create the alias "minus" for the set "difference" method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, alias

Since minus is often used in set theory books for difference, I tried to alias difference to minus in Python by

minus = difference

but I got

NameError: name 'difference' is not defined

Is there a way to do what I want?

= works for aliasing function names but apparently not for methods

Comment: Are you aware that you can *already* write `a - b` to compute the set difference between `a` and `b`? No need to create a new method named `minus` which, at any rate, wouldn’t be as readable as `a - b`.

Comment: `difference` is not a global name anyway; it's an attribute of the `set` class. *If* you could add new attributes to `set`, you could write `set.minus = set.difference`, but

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom subclass of set, with a minus method that calls set's `__sub__` method.

Example:

```
class SetWithDifference(set):
    def minus(self, other):
        return self.__sub__(other)


a = SetWithDifference({'a', 'b', 'c'})
b = SetWithDifference({'a', 'b'})
print(a.minus(b))
```